# Ruby on Rails uninitialized constant ParagraphsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just been trying to clean up a little bit in my Ruby on Rails application. I found that I had a Paragraph scaffold that was completely unnecessary, since the data was only being rendered in another form. Therefore, I deleted this Paragraph scaffold, added a Paragraph model and Controller, and then also added "resource paragraphs" back to my routes. Now I'm getting this error:

```
uninitialized constant ParagraphsController
```

Here are the examples of the files that I have:

```
#controllers/paragraph_controller.rb
class ParagraphController < ApplicationController
    def destroy
        Paragraph.find(params[:id]).destroy
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back}
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
    end
end
```

.

```
#models/paragraph.rb
class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :page
end
```

.

```
#db/migrate:
class CreateParagraphs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :paragraphs do |t|
      t.integer :page_id
      t.string :description
      t.string :paragraph_type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

.

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do  

  ##removed unnecessary stuff
  resources :paragraphs
end
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. It happens when I click this link:

```
<%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>".html_safe, paragraph, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger", title: "Delete paragraph" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `ParagraphController`, without the 's', not `ParagraphsController`.

Comment: Thank you!! Didn't even catch this.

Comment: It happens to the best of us @user3447014 :P

Comment: Indeed. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

It should be ParagraphsController (plural) and change the filename as well.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even catch this!